# alternative to storing api keys in migration yaml files?

Tags: 8, migrations, configuration

I've created a yaml file to import Twitter timeline items (not super simple since documentation on the `migrate_plus` OAuth plugin seems to be few and far between); this migration naturally requires the use of ostensibly-secret API information. I'd like to keep this out of the yaml and I've seen answers (like [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191664/how-can-i-exclude-api-keys-passwords-and-so-on-from-configuration-management)) that talk about setting things in code, but I'm wondering if there's another customer-serviceable way. For example, here's my config file, called `migrate_plus.migration.migrate_sample_twitter`:

```
id: migrate_sample_twitter
label: Sample Twitter Migration
dependencies:
  - migrate
  - migrate_plus
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  authentication:
    plugin: oauth2
    base_uri: 'https://api.twitter.com'
    token_url: /oauth2/token
    grant_type: client_credentials
    client_id: <twitter app consumer key>
    client_secret: <twitter app consumer secret>

  urls: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=tmountjr

  fields:
    -
      name: id
      label: Tweet ID
      selector: id_str

destination:
  plugin: table
  table_name: twitter_import
  id_fields:
    id:
      type: string
```

Now, running `drush cget migrate_plus.migration.migrate_sample_twitter` drops all that information on the console, which is fine. BUT, I'm unable to retrieve any information deeper than that. What I was hoping to do was, in my `settings.local.php`, specify this:

```
$conf['migrate_plus.migration.migrate_sample_twitter.source.authentication.client_id'] = 'consumer key here'
$conf['migrate_plus.migration.migrate_sample_twitter.source.authentication.client_secret'] = 'consumer secret here'
```

...and then just omit the `client_id` and `client_secret` keys from the yaml file. But that doesn't seem to work; when I make those changes and run `drush migrate-status` I get an error: `The config is missing the following key: "client_id"`.

So short version of this question: is there any way to omit values from an exported yaml file and instead have those values stored in a user-editable settings file that can be `.gitignore`d from the repo?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, If the migration is one that is a config entity (shows up in /config rather than in migrations/) values can be overridden in settings.php or environment specific settings.

```
// Set migration settings from environment variables.
$config['migrate_plus.migration.node_article']['source']['urls'] = [getenv('CMS_ARTICLE_API_URL') . '/services/articles/facilities/all'];
$config['migrate_plus.migration.node_article']['source']['headers']['apikey'] = getenv('CMS_ARTICLE_API_KEY');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this will work in your use case, but I know the [`key` module](https://www.drupal.org/project/key) is designed to keep secret keys outside of any config files.  Then you just ask the `key` service for whatever key you need and it returns it to you.  It can store the key in several different formats.

Comment: Doesn't look like that module ties in (at least not directly) with config files, though I suppose it would be possible to write a plugin for `migrate` that would read from that service, but at that point, might as well just point at `settings.php` to keep things lean.

Answer (score 0):

$conf is 7.x, Drupal 8 uses $config for configuration overrides and the syntax is `$config['config_object']['property.path.key'].

In your case, should be something like:

$config['migrate_plus.migration.migrate_sample_twitter']['source.authentication.client_id'] = 'consumer key here';

That should work but keep in mind that migrations are cached unless you disable the cache by setting the bin to null, so don't forget to clear caches.

Comment: Not working for this module, but it could be a handful of things. I'll try modifying a system configuration file, not a contrib module file, and see if that process works.