# How to determine the code for settings.php config override based on .yml?

Tags: 8, security, configuration

I am trying to [put my API keys in a separate file instead of storing them in config management.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191664/how-can-i-exclude-api-keys-passwords-and-so-on-from-configuration-management)

For example, I installed the Commerce Stripe module.

When I export the config, it looks like this:

**commerce_payment.comerce_payment_gateway.stripe_test.yml**

```
uuid: 430a9544-c852-4a14-b7b0-3a833a02dd06
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - commerce_stripe
id: stripe_test
label: 'Stripe Test'
weight: null
plugin: stripe
configuration:
  publishable_key: thisishidden
  secret_key: thisishidden
  display_label: Stripe
  mode: test
  payment_method_types:
    - credit_card
conditions: {  }
conditionOperator: AND
```

Now, I want to store `publishable_key` and `secret_key` in a file, but **how do I determine the "path" to call them?**

```
$config['whatgoeshere?']['configuration']['secret_key'] = 'abcdefg';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first key is the name of the config object/file, so... `commerce_payment.comerce_payment_gateway.stripe_test`.

The rest you already figured out, it's an array that's recursively merged into the other one.

Comment: Actually its more like ```$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;``` ... just to be clear about the structure. So the root(fist key) is the config name(yml file name) and the rest is structure as set in the config(yml) file itself.

Comment: true, I was answering specifically to the "whatgoeshere?" part in the question, there already is example with just that part missing

Comment: This is not available in any documentation anywhere that I was able to find! (With regards to how to reference the nested yaml items)

Comment: @NikLP there are several examples in settings.php, as a start.

Comment: You're correct (naturally). I had not been able to see this clearly enough to formulate a correlation between the nested yamls and the array syntax. We might do well to add a small entry in the docs on config overrides outlining this specific syntax.